# If a smooth projective curve $X$ has a divisor $D$ with $\deg D = 1$ and $\dim(\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(D))\geq 2$, it is of genus zero.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a projective smooth curve of genus $g$. If there exists $D \in \operatorname{Div}(X)$ with $\deg(D)=1$ and $\dim(\Gamma (O_X(D)) \geq 2$, then $g =0$. That is equivalent with the fact that $X \cong \mathbb P^1$, no? I don't know how to start.

Comment: Yes it is equivalent to show that $X \cong \Bbb P^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a two-step proof:

1) Show that if a smooth projective curve admits distinct points, which are linear equivalent, then the curve is ismorphic to $\mathbb P^1$. The reasoning is similiar to the hint of the other answer: If $x \neq y$ are linear equivalent, we have a rational function, which has a pole at $y$ and a zero at $x$ and no other poles or zeroes. Such a rational function is nothing else but an isomorphism $X \to \mathbb P^1$.

2) Now $\dim \mathcal O_X(D) \geq 2$ shows that the set of effective divisors, which are linear equivalent to $D$ is not a singleton, because this set is in bijection to $(\mathcal O_X(D) \setminus \{0\})/k^*$. But an effective divisor of degree $1$ is just a point and by 1) this set can only be larger than a singleton if $X = \mathbb P^1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is Hartshorne's exercise 4.1.5, which asks you to prove $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(D))\leq deg D+1$, with equality iff $D=0$ or $g=0$.

To see this, by Riemann Roch, you can see this is equivalent to proving that $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(K-D))\leq g=h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(K))$. And this claim is true since under your assumpition, $D$ is an effective divisor.

To see when the equality holds, it is clear that if $D=0$ or $g=0$, we have the equality in the first claim. The case when $g=1$ is also easy. In the case of $g\geq 2$, you have the classical result saying that $|K|$ has no base points( Hartshorne 4.5.1), which implies $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(K-D))=h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(K))-1$, so equality cannot hold in this case.

With the exercise done, apply directly to your case, as $D$ is not trivial, we get $g=0$.

Comment: Isn't this solution a bit overkilled ?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was hoping the general statement proved here might be helpful. Btw, like your answer upstairs.

Comment: Thanks ! I also like your answer, I didn't know this statement (but with RR nothing can resist :) )